# Retrieve elements by class and store attribute in a CSV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML page which has a lot of characters. I want to save only elements of a specific class into a CSV file or to somehow export only elements of specific class. For example:

```
<a href="/n/lucaslucco" class="profimg">
    <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xat1/t51.2885-19/11358188_704898589633208_839585839_a.jpg" alt="" width="40" height="40" />
</a>
```

I have a lot of these in my HTML, but I want to save only the link. I tried to get elements by class, but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Looks like XY problem, instead of trying to solve the actual problem you confusing us that you can't do something else, but something else solving doesn't help you to get the right answer.

Comment: What exactly are you saving to the CSV file? Show what you tried to do that is not working.

Comment: @epascarello saving the image link, in this case is this one https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xat1/t51.2885-19/11358188_704898589633208_839585839_a.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just select the images you want and use map to get the image sources.

```js
var imgs = $("a.profimg img")
             .map( function (ind, elm) { 
                 return elm.src; 
              })
             .get();
console.log(imgs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/n/lucaslucco" class="profimg"><img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xat1/t51.2885-19/11358188_704898589633208_839585839_a.jpg" alt="" width="40" height="40"></a>
<a href="/n/lucaslucco" class="profimg"><img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xat1/t51.2885-19/11358188_704898589633208_839585839_a.jpg" alt="" width="40" height="40"></a>
<a href="/n/lucaslucco" class="xxx"><img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xat1/t51.2885-19/11358188_704898589633208_839585839_a.jpg" alt="" width="40" height="40"></a>
```